# Adding class to list as instance

Tags: python, pyglet

I have the below code:

```
classes = [Class1(), Class2(), Class3()]
usedClasses = {}

number = random.randint(0, len(classes)-1)
usedClasses[len(usedClasses)] = classes[number]
```

This code randomly selects a class from `classes` and then adds this to `usedClasses` however, when I apply a method to a class in `usedClasses`, any duplicate additions are classed as the same instance. How would I add a class from `classes` to `usedClasses` as an instance each time.

Comment: Can you post an example of the issue in action?

Comment: It sounds like you might be using `class` variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have a list of the classes themselves, not instances, and instatiate them when required:

```
classes = [Class1, Class2, Class3] # Just the names of the classes
usedClasses = {}

number = random.randint(0, len(classes)-1)
usedClasses[len(usedClasses)] = classes[number]() # create a new instance here.
```